# Selecting lag length for VAR Model. Differences or Levels?

Tags: data-transformation, model-selection, stata, vector-autoregression, lags

I'm currently testing for optimal VAR lag length using the information criteria. I found that my variables are non-stationary (i.e. they have to be first differenced). When I identify the number of lags in Stata, do I test them in first differences or in levels?